# python Encoding Problem?

Tags: python

I read from source.sql ( sql script ) file

```
INSERT INTO `Tbl_abc` VALUES (1111, 2222, 'CLEMENT', 'taya', 'MME', 'Gérant', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 4688, 0, NULL, NULL, 'MAILLOT 01/02/09', 'MAILLOT 01/04/09', NULL, NULL);
```

And write to dest.sql With my list formated

I met the problem with encoding for example:

```
Gérant= G\xc3\xa9rant
```

WHAT I AM TRYING

```
def DataMigration(dest, source, tbl_name, return_data=True):
    '''      
    '''
    data = []
    for ln in codecs.open(source, 'r', "utf-8").xreadlines():
        replace1 = ln.replace("INSERT INTO `"+tbl_name+"` VALUES (", "")
        replace2 = replace1.replace(");", "")
        list_replace = replace2.split(',')        
        s = list_replace
        data.append(list_replace)

    if return_data == True:
        ouputdata = [d for d in data if d[1] == ' 0' and d[6]==' 0']
        return ouputdata
    if return_data == False:
        return data
```

I print 
print DataMigration('dest.sql', '.source.sql', 'Tbl_abc', False)

OUTPUT

```
  [['1111', ' 2222', " 'CLEMENT'", " 'taya'", " 'MME'", " 'G\xc3\xa9rant'", ' NULL', ' NULL', ' NULL', ' NULL', ' NULL', ' NULL', ' NULL', ' 4688', ' 0', ' NULL', ' NULL', " 'MAILLOT 01/04/09'", " 'MAILLOT 01/04/09'", ' NULL', ' NULL']]


But My Ouput file still has the problem.Any Could help me ?
```

Comment: Just a thought: Did you check your table definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use `.encode("utf-8")`, when you write to .sql file too.

open the file

```
fileObj = codecs.open( "someFile", "r", "utf-8" )
```

lets say you read it

```
data=fileOjb.read()
```

... do something on data

```
open("newfile","w").write(data.encode("utf-8"))
```

Comment: Can I assume that, you want `Gérant` instead of `G\xc3\xa9rant` in .sql file?

Answer (score 0):

Hi check encoding of your file .sql maybe it is not utf-8!

Answer (score 0):

Store your working data internally in Python as Unicode (use decode on read), and always write out using encode.

In your instance, you need to know the encoding of your database to know the correct output encoding.